# Translate node with node fields

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using the [Node Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_field) module. When I translate a node its respective node fields are not copied to the translation, forcing me to recreate them by hand. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking this here instead of in the module's issue queue? https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/node_field?categories=All  Questions like "Does this module support translations?" are probably best addressed in the drupal.org issue queues.

Comment: I've created an issue now: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_field/issues/2926048

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by using hook_node_insert:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {

  // Only act if we are dealing with a content type supporting translations.

  if (translation_supported_type($node->type)) {

    if ($node->tnid != $node->nid) {

      $sql = "INSERT INTO node_field( nid, type ,title ,machine_name ,show_title ,hidden ,value ,weight ,settings) 
          SELECT :new_node, type, title, machine_name, show_title, hidden, value, weight, settings 
          FROM node_field 
          WHERE nid=:old_node";

      db_query($sql, array(':new_node' => $node->nid, ':old_node' => $node->tnid));
    }
  }
}
```